# Adding entire string array to adapter

Tags: android, string, spinner, adapter, arrays

I'm sure this has already been asked, so if somebody can refer me to another thread that'd be great.

I've got a string array:

```
    String animalArray[] = {"Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Snake"};
```

And I've got a spinner with an adapter. How do I avoid having to do this?:

```
    adapter1.add(animalArray[0]);
    adapter1.add(animalArray[1]);
    adapter1.add(animalArray[2]);
    adapter1.add(animalArray[3]);
```

Can I use a for loop or something? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter(if you are talking about it)  [counstructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29) can solve the problem. 
It can use String array as data sourse, **T[] objects**.

**UPD** sample code:

```
for(int i=0;i<animalArray.length;i++){
   adapter1.add(animalArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to use an ArrayAdapter because it doesn't let me add to the String ArrayList from the xml file. I want to be able to have the adapter populate dynamically depending on which animals I put into the string.

Comment: Then just loop though String array.

Comment: Works great, thanks! For future people who see this, you're missing a `)` before the `;`

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array and add them like this:

```
for (String s : animalArray) {
    adapter1.add(s);
}
```